# Is the infinite sum $ G(z) = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{z^j}{j !} (1 + j)^{-3/2} $ familiar?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a sum that comes as a special case of my original sum. I do not want to show the original sum as it is too complicated. The specific one looks like the following:

$$ G(z) = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{z^j}{j !} (1 + j)^{-\frac{3}{2}}  $$

Does it belong to any known summations in literature? It should be a converging one, but I have no idea how to approach it.

---

#### Edit

In this edit, I am writing the generic sum I had in the beginning:

$$ G(z) = \frac{\Gamma(1 + n)}{\Lambda^{n+1}}  \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\frac{\Lambda}{C}}{\frac{\Lambda}{C} + j}\right)^{n+1} \frac{z^j}{j!}  $$

$\Lambda, C, n > 0$

The special case above is for $\Lambda = 1, C = 1, n = 1/2$. For integer $n$, it is a hypergeometric function, but I wanted to know what it is when $n$ is not an integer.

Mathematica refuses to proceed.

---

#### Edit 2

Or, can there be a closed form of this sum that can be computed; like an asymptotic solution?

Comment: Well, $G(1)$ normalized (without $\sqrt{\pi}/2$ is $\approx 1.47499033583…$ which down seem to be in closed form.

Comment: @TianVlašić How did you arrive at this for $G(1)$ ?

Comment: However, note that you have $\frac{Chi(z)+Shi(z)-log(z)-\gamma}{z} \leq G(z) \leq \frac{e^z-1}{z}$.

Comment: @TianVlašić Could you please elaborate? It seems very interesting, but I don't know about Chi or Shi .

Comment: Of course, they refer to hyperbolic trigonometric integrals; see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral.

Comment: I will edit the question with the generic sum. I am curious now.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. Wherever I wrote $G(z)$, I am referring the the normalized form.

Comment: Just to establish that the series is, indeed, converging: we can ignore the $\sqrt{\pi}/2$ if all we're interested in is convergence; $\sum(z^j/j!)$ is of course convergent, and since $(1+j)^{-3/2}\le1$ the given series converges by comparison to $\sum(z^j/j!)$.

Comment: $2zG(z)/\sqrt\pi=\sum_{j\ge1}z^j/(j!\sqrt j)$ so see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750174 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264595

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not an answer; just observations.*

As @TianVlašić already commented,  if
$$G(z) = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{z^j}{j !} (1 + j)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$F(z)=-\frac{\log (-z)+\Gamma (0,-z)+\gamma }{z}<G(z) 
 <\frac{e^z-1}{z}=H(z)$$

Look at the plots of $\sqrt{F(z)\,H(z)}$ and $G(z)$ : they are extremely close to eachother.

*May be*,
$$G(z) \sim F^a(z)\times H^{1-a}(z)$$ for some $a \in (0,1)$ $\cdots$ to be found.

Comment: Wow. Nice insight. How did you find that inequality on the first place? And, is it possible to say something similar for the general expression of $G(z)$ in my Edit ?

Comment: @CfourPiO. The problem is simple with expoents $\frac 22=1$ and $\frac 42=2$. This give the two bounds. Now  $\frac{1+2}3=\frac 32$. This was the idea and why I immediately tried the square root of the bounding functions.. For the other one, I am working (with little hope). Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it. In the meanwhile, I will also try the general case; to have the similar inequalities. In that case, I know that for integer exponents nearing $n+1$, the functions are generalised hyper geometric functions. $H(z)/F(z) = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Lambda^{n+1}} _{(\text{round/floor}(n+1))} F_{(\text{round/floor}(n+1))} (\Lambda/c_3, \Lambda/c_3, …, \Lambda/c_3; \Lambda/c_3+1, \Lambda/c_3+1, \Lambda/c_3+1,…, \Lambda/c_3+1; z)$. So, the bounding functions are; one with round and one with floor.

Answer (score 1):

$$ S=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{j=0}\frac{z^j}{j!}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s(j+1)}\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\Gamma(3/2)}ds=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s+ze^{-s}}\sqrt{s}ds=\int_0^1(-\log y)^{1/2}e^{zy}dy.$$

Edit.

$$\Gamma(\alpha)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(c+j)^{\alpha}}\frac{z^j}{j!}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-cs+ze^s}s^{\alpha-1}ds=\int_0^1y^{c-1}(-\log y)^{\alpha-1}e^{zy}dy.$$

Comment: What would you like to know about this function $z\mapsto G(z)=\int_0^1(-\log y)^{1/2}e^{zy}?$ A remarkable point is that $\log G$ is convex on $R$ (from Holder ) with its derivative valued in $(0,1).$

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know if this function can be represented as a closed form; or a form that can be formed with special functions. The reason I wanted it because if one tries numerically to obtain a value for $G(z)$, it explodes because of the infinite sum. However, mathematically it can be proven that it is a converging function. If it can be represented as a combination of special functions like hyper-geometric, logarithmic, or Bessel, there are numerical methods to properly compute these functions. I like your answer, I appreciate it. However, I am also thinking how to generalize it.

Comment: By generalize, I mean how to deal with the sum with any non-integer $n$.

Comment: I have added an edit for answering to  your question for general $n.$

Comment: I appreciate the effort @Gerard . Thanks a lot for helping out really :) However, I don't see the edit, was it a technical glitch?

Comment: Hum, it seems that I did a wrong click. Look :  you have still a nice Laplace transform of a positive density.

Comment: Nice! How did you come up with the second line? The integral form?

Comment: I suppose that you mean $\frac{1}{A^{\alpha}}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-As}\frac{s^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}ds$ with $A=c+j.$

Comment: Funny thing is now I realized that my original problem was the second expression you shared. I started with that actually and expanded the exponential $e^{ze^{-s}}$ into an infinite sum and then took the  integral inside the sum and had the problem I shared here. Now, that I arrived at the problem again with your second expression, I realize that I could have proceeded to the third expression you shared. $\int_0^1y^{c-1}(-\log y)^{\alpha-1}e^{zy}dy.$ Is there an advantage for computing the third expression, because it is an integral from $0$ to $1$? Or, can it be reduced further?

Comment: Also, in the second expression, I think it is $e^{ze^{-s}}$ instead of $e^{ze^{s}}$. Am I right?